# Why does the text within the div appear outside it on a browser?

Tags: html, css

there is "div" and the width is "100px"

```html
<div style=" width:190px;border:1px solid #DAD7D7;border-radius:5px;padding:5px;">
  text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,
</div>
```

The problem is text outside  the framework of the div.What is the solution Regardless of the spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break it into two lines using

```
word-break: break-all;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uaaytgfq/

Or you can set overflow (show scrollbar or hide everything outside element):

```
div {overflow: auto}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uaaytgfq/1/

```
div {overflow: hidden}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uaaytgfq/2/

Comment: This is a perfect use case for stack snippets. This is the right answer IMO but, I am lazy and don't want to leave SO to view the output :(

Answer (score 1):

use `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
div {
    width:190px;
    border:1px solid #DAD7D7;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use min-width and display inline

```html
<div style="min-width:190px;border:1px solid #DAD7D7;border-radius:5px;padding:5px; display: inline">
  text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,
</div>
```